# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: docker

How can I solve this problem?

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.
Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'
```

Comment: maybe try running `sudo docker` instead of just `docker`

Comment: Yep, just solved the problem helped by this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34869632/7431693. Thanks John.

Comment: gunbert, check this out https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/